# How to remove possible suffix repetitions from a str column?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe, where the suffix in a `str` column **might** be repeating itself:

```py
    Book
0   Book1.pdf
1   Book2.pdf.pdf
2   Book3.epub
3   Book4.mobi.mobi
4   Book5.epub.epub
```

Desired output (removed suffixes where needed)

```py
    Book
0   Book1.pdf
1   Book2.pdf
2   Book3.epub
3   Book4.mobi
4   Book5.epub
```

I have tried splitting on the `.` character and then counting occurences of the last item to check if there is duplication.

*I have used file paths only to illustrate my point! The contents of the column could be something different than paths!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex with a capturing group + reference and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Book'] = df['Book'].str.replace(r'(\.[^.]+)\1$', r'\1', regex=True)

# or
df['Book'] = df['Book'].str.replace(r'(\.[^.]+)(?=\1)$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
         Book
0   Book1.pdf
1   Book2.pdf
2  Book3.epub
3  Book4.mobi
4  Book5.epub
```

[regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/ImfgxR/1)

[regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/h2Ojj8/1)

##### generalization

if you want something generic that doesn't depend on the `.`:

```
df['Book'] = df['Book'].str.replace(r'(.+)\1$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Iu5kY/1)